# Can my python script know if it started manualy from IDE or automatically from scheduler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduler

So i have a python script that automate some checks and send a mail when finished.
I start the script with windows scheduler every night.
I want to log if the script ran from the scheduler or if someone ran it manualy from an IDE(PyCharm for my case)
Is there any os method that returns how a script ran or something else maybe?

Comment: Pass it as a command line argument? Or have an environment variable set in the scheduler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while scheduling from windows scheduler you can send a command line argument, then check it in your code if it is started with specified command line argument then it is run from windows scheduler.

Comment: Worked perfectly, I thought about this solution but for some reason I feared passing a cmd argument will force me to pass atleast 1 argument for every run.